# How to validate nested polymorphic schemas in mongoose?

Tags: mongoose, polymorphism

Mongoose support polymorphic relations assuming documents lives in different collections. But what's the case when you have a document, that inside has a polymorphic collection/relation.

For example, let's say we have a `Page` model, and inside basically has a list of `components` it contains, each component has a type, and depending on the type it has properties.

For example:

```js
{
  title: "Main Page",
  components: [
    {
      type: 'title',
      text: 'Hello!',
      size: 'big'
    },
    {
      type: 'button',
      text: 'Click me!',
      onClick: 'BUTTON_CLICKED'
    }
  ]
}
```

Here I have 2 components one of type `Title` and one of type `Button`, they have/require different properties.

Now, what's the suggested way of defining a schema, in a way we can validate differently each component, based on the `type`?

Comment: I'd be more inclined to just do it myself than get mongoose to do it for me. It's a pretty simple `if` statement with an existence check and key validation using `.hasOwnProperty()`.

Comment: @cdbajorin that's my typical approach, but I wanted to take advantage of the mongoose schema definition to validate objects.